# How to model variant data structures in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

How would you model a variant data structure in XML Schema, without using `xsi:type`?
My goal is to define a schema for an element named `<property>` whose attributes and attribute types depend on the `datatype` attribute; for example:

```
<property datatype="integer" default="1234"/>
<property datatype="string" default="Abcde" maxlength="255"/>
```

Here, the `default` attribute of the integer-typed property shall only accept valid integer values, whereas the `default` attribute of the string-typed property shall accept any characters.

Furthermore, the `maxlength` attribute shall be allowed only if `datatype="string"`.

I.e. a schema validation error should occur on both of the following properties:

```
<property datatype="integer" default="NotAnInteger"/>
<property datatype="integer" default="12345" maxlength="100"/>  <!-- maxlength not allowed -->
```

I know that if I would use `xsi:type` instead of `datatype`, this would be easy to model in XML Schema. 
There are, however, at least two reasons, why I do not want to use `xsi:type` here:

- I have read in many places that it is not considered good style to use `xsi:type`, e.g. [xsi:type
  is Evil](http://blog.whatfettle.com/2006/11/29/xsitype-is-evil/) or [Smart but useless, part 3](http://www.proxml.be/users/paul/weblog/4db4c/Smart_but_useless_part_3.html).
- The name `xsi:type` simply does not express the purpose of the attribute precisely enough.
  I rather would prefer `datatype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Conditional Type Assignment in XSD 1.1, which is implemented in current releases of Xerces and Saxon. It can't be done in XSD 1.0 - it's a well known restriction (often referred to under the label "co-occurrence constraints").

Comment: Conditional Type Assignment (= `<alternative>`) sounds like what I need. Unfortunately, the XML Schema 1.1 standard is not yet released, and therefore many XML processors are not yet compatible with XML Schema 1.1. Does XML Schema 1.0 offer anything that would solve my problem?